# Erro [Cannot GET] ao simular minha aplicação com lite-server com typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou com erro ao simular minha aplicação em typescript, o erro gerado é:

```
Cannot GET /
```

O meu arquivo tsconfig.json da minha aplicação é simples, somente contém as seguintes configurações:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "assets/js",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "module": "system",
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": [
        "assets/ts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Estou tirando um print da raiz do meu projeto caso o erro seja de repositório:

[image: Diretório da minha aplicação]

Agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: Não tem nenhum erro no console? Se ainda não tentou ver, poderia tentar apertar F12 e nos falar se possui algum erro para tentarmos resolver.